# Linking jsoncpp (libjson)

Tags: c++, macos, libjson

I'm trying to link jsoncpp ([lib_json](https://github.com/vincenthz/libjson)) with a c++ project using cmake. It works perfectly fine on one computer, but on another one (with pretty much the same config) i get an error when i execute my app :

> dyld: Library not loaded: buildscons/linux-gcc-4.2.1/src/lib_json/libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.dylib
>
> Referenced from: path to executable
>
> Reason: image not found

Any idea what might be causing this ? I don't even understand why it tries to look @ buildscons/linux-gcc-4.2.1/src/lib_json/libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.dylib since i put jsoncpp in usr/lib/ and changed the name to libjsoncpp and cmake find the correct path/library.

I also built jsoncpp the exact same way on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you run `tool -L libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.dylib` you can see some weird relative address to your `libjson...`. I guess if you replicated this directory structure it would work but that's a bad solution.

What I did instead is that I used `.a` (`libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.a`) and linked it staticaly with my binary. In XCode simply under `Build Settings` -> `Linking` -> `Other Linker Flags` I added absolute path to my `.a`. For me it was `/Users/martin/Downloads/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.2.1/libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.a` and that's all.

Of course, I don't know your use case, maybe you really need to link it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I see now, you mean [libjson](https://github.com/vincenthz/libjson), and not [libjsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) (they're different!)

In your titel you talk about jsoncpp, and that's what this answer is for.
But maybe it's useful for people who got confused by the titel too.

---

You can '**amalgamate**' jsoncpp.

From jsoncpp source dir run `python amalgamate.py` which creates:

```
dist/jsoncpp.cpp
dist/json/json.h
dist/json/json-forwards.h
```

Now you have to **compile** `jsoncpp.cpp` **once** and just **link against** the resulting `jsoncpp.o`:

1. `g++ -o jsoncpp.o -c jsoncpp.cpp` (only once)
2. `g++ -o executable jsoncpp.o main.cpp` (every time)

If you get errors, you might have to `#define JSON_IS_AMALGAMATION` before including `json/json.h`, but ...

... I tried it and it worked for me. (without `#define JSON_IS_AMALGAMATION`, that is)

#### Used code:

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include "json/json-forwards.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Json::Reader    reader;
    Json::Value     value;
    if (!reader.parse("{\"hello\":\"world\"}", value, false))
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't parse Json: " << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << value.toStyledString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```